# Get dropdown title to change to selected dropdown value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react and trying to pick this up by following some tutorials but I am having some issues getting the dropdown list title to change based on the value that was selected in the drop down list. I'm using `react bootstrap` to try to do this but am not sure how to get the title to change.

Right now, when ever the drop down is selected, I call `onDropChange` function and I'm trying to set the state to the value of the dropdown that was selected so then I can use it in the title, but I can't even get that to work.

Here is my code so far:

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import * as courseActions from '../../actions/courseActions';
import * as ReactBootstrap from 'react-bootstrap';

class CoursesPage extends React.Component {

    constructor (props, context) {
        super(props, context);

        this.state = {
            course: {title: ""},
            drplist: {drpval: ""}
        };

        this.onTitleChange = this.onTitleChange.bind(this);
        this.onClickSave = this.onClickSave.bind(this);
        this.onDropChange = this.onDropChange.bind(this);
    }

    onTitleChange (event) {
        //console.log("event: ", event)
        const course = this.state.course;
        //  console.log("course: ", course);
        course.title = event.target.value;
        this.setState({course: course});
    }

    onClickSave () {
        this.props.dispatch(courseActions.createCourse(this.state.course));
    }

    courseRow(course, index) {
        return <div key={index}>{course.title}</div>
    }

    onDropChange (eventKey) {
        console.log("drop change: ", eventKey);
        const drplist = this.state.drplist;
        drplist.drpval = eventKey;
        console.log('title2:', drplist.drpval);
    }

    render (title) {

        let data = [1,2,3,4]

        const makeList = function(x) {
            return <ReactBootstrap.MenuItem eventKey={x}>{x}</ReactBootstrap.MenuItem>
        }

        console.log("title:", title)

        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Courses</h1>
                {this.props.courses.map(this.courseRow)}
                <h2>Add Course</h2>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    onChange={this.onTitleChange}
                    value={this.state.course.title} />
                <input
                    type="submit"
                    value="save"
                    onClick={this.onClickSave} />
                <ReactBootstrap.DropdownButton title="test drop" id="bg-vertical-1" onSelect={this.onDropChange}>{data.map(makeList)}</ReactBootstrap.DropdownButton>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return {
      courses: state.courses  
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps) (CoursesPage);
```

-------EDIT-------

I think I'm getting some where:

I made the initial state look like this:

```
this.state = {
    course: {title: ""},
    drplist: {drpval: "Drop Down"}
};
```

I then changed the render part to this:

```
        <ReactBootstrap.DropdownButton title={this.state.drplist.drpval} id="bg-vertical-1" onSelect={this.onDropChange}>{data.map(makeList)}</ReactBootstrap.DropdownButton>
```

but `title={this.state.drplist.drpval}` doesn't seem to reflect the updated state...

Comment: Try `this.onDropChange()`

Comment: that didn't seem to work...when I did that, it doesn't even launch the `onDropChange` function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set/update the state correctly. Both `course` and `drplist` are objects. So when an update to these objects happens, you need to "let React know" about the update, so it knows that it needs to re-render something. A "hack" would be to call `this.forceUpdate()` after `console.log('title2:', drplist.drpval);`.

However, the correct thing would be to update the state correctly. Instead of directly manipulating the object values, first clone the state object you want to update, and then use `this.setState` to inform React about the update. So change your `onDropChange` function to.

```
console.log("drop change: ", eventKey);
//make a shallow-copy of the drplist object
let drplist = Object.assign({}, this.state.drplist);
drplist.drpval = eventKey;
console.log('title2:', drplist.drpval);
this.setState({drplist: drplist});
```

A similar bug is in your `onTitleChange`

Answer (score 1):

You are mutating your state. I strongly suggest you to read about [immutability in React](https://medium.com/pro-react/a-brief-talk-about-immutability-and-react-s-helpers-70919ab8ae7c#.63ea5ucgf).

```
onTitleChange (event) {
    const course = this.state.course;
    this.setState({
        course: {
            ...this.course,
            title: event.target.value
        }
    });
}
```

Make sure the [object spread operator plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/) is enabled in your babel configuration. Otherwise, you may use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).